# i want to hit API url from Image tag src ti keep track of email read or unread

Tags: php, laravel, html-email, email-attachments, email-templates

**Iam passing my API url as  src="" in  tag like this; to keep track of email is read or not by user here is code:**

```
<img src="http://localhost/api/mailopen/{{$data['invoiceID']}}" style='display: none;'/>
```

**But gmail is attaching additional content in my image src attribute.**

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/sRUEIB06nvaNFtm_eK_53l90yhrJeFfEYcN0tpdn7xJx--3F72hNQOd9H5CKkpObI9bcFuOMzC5dd_5nETv0Dfs=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost/api/mailopen/93" style="display:none" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:W2ZhbHNlLDJd">
```

when you see above URL created by gmail you can see my API route after "#" symbol.

> My question is that how can i hit my API from email to keep track of
> email read or not.?

*Note: I want it to done automatically when user open email not by clicking on anchor tag.*

Comment: Check out [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/jdavidbakr/mail-tracker) which might be better and easier than building it all yourself.

Comment: @Peppermintology can you help with this one?

Comment: Have you looked at the package? What have you tried?

Comment: actually i don't want to use package. can you help me that code which iam using ?

Comment: I suggest you investigate how the package I have linked works and use that as a starting point.